# `jq` hangs when I provide `--arg` and a template json

Tags: jq

I am trying to use `jq` to create a json from a template json file using `--args` and the template file. When I execute the below command, `jq` just hangs in there forever.

I am a rookie with `jq`, would really appreciate if someone can point out what am I doing wrong.
**template.jq**

```
{
  "channel": "channel",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "color": "#a7dbb5",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "header",
          "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": $SUMMARY,
            "emoji": true
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Build ID:         *  <\($BUILD_URL)|\($BUILD_ID)>\n*Duration:*        \($DURATION)\n*User:                *<\($USER_EMAIL)|\($USER_NAME)>\n*Test Cases:*     \($TEST_CASES)"
          },
          "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sudas-px/dev-repo/main/check.png",
            "alt_text": "status thumbnail"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*Portworx*\nv\($PX_VERSION)"
            },
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*PX Backup*\nv\($PX_BACKUP_VERSION)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*Stork Image:*\n\($STORK_IMAGE)"
            },
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*Kubernetes:*\nv\($K8S_VERSION)"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*Github Repository*"
            },
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": $GITHUB_REPO
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "section",
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "*Branch*"
            },
            {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": $GITHUB_BRANCH
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "divider"
        },
        {
          "type": "actions",
          "block_id": "actionblock789",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "View Pipeline"
              },
              "style": "primary",
              "url": $BUILD_URL
            },
            {
              "type": "button",
              "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "View Logs"
              },
              "url": $KIBANA_URL
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the command I ran

```
jq --arg SUMMARY "Summary" --arg BUILD_ID "BUILD_ID" --arg BUILD_URL "BUILD_URL" --arg DURATION "DURATION" --arg USER_EMAIL "EMAIL" --arg USER_NAME "USER" --arg TEST_CASES 3 --arg PX_VERSION "VERSION" --arg PX_BACKUP_VERSION "PX_VERSION" --arg STORK_IMAGE "IMAGE_STORK" --arg K8S_VERSION "1.23.0" --arg GITHUB_BRANCH "branch" --arg GITHUB_REPO "repo" --arg KIBANA_URL "url" -f template.jq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "template" is just a filter that requires no input, but you forgot to tell `jq` that the filter won't need any input. As a result, `jq` is waiting to read from standard input. Use the `-n` option to tell `jq` it doesn't need to read from standard input.

```
jq -n <lots of --args> -f template.jq
```